# List Subscribers APIのパラメーターについて

Tags: soracom

SORACOMの[List Subscribers API リファレンス](https://dev.soracom.io/jp/docs/api/#!/Subscriber/list_subscribers)にてParamtersのstatus_filterおよびspeed_class_filterについて、それぞれ「指定可能な値の一覧はこちら」と記載されていますがリンクがないようです。

これらに指定可能な値の一覧が記載されている画面をご存じの方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか。

おそらくResponse Bodyの該当する値と同じものだと思いますが、Responseに取りうる値の記載もないようです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API リファレンスを更新して、設定可能な値のリストを追記させていただきました。

status_filter には `active` `inactive` `ready` `instock` `shipped` `suspended` `terminated` のいずれかの文字列、もしくはそれらのうち複数の文字列を `|` で接続して指定することができます。
（例： 'active|inactive|ready'）

speed_class_filter には現時点では `s1.minimum` `s1.slow` `s1.standard` `s1.fast` のいずれかの文字列、もしくはそれらのうち複数の文字列を `|` で接続して指定することができます。
（例： 's1.standard|s1.fast'）

Comment: さっそくありがとうございます！
status_filterの方は順に、ユーザーコンソールのフィルターにある 使用中 休止中 準備完了 出荷前 出荷済 強制停止中 解約済み に対応しているということですね。
readyはIMSI登録直後activeになる直前になっていたのを見ました。
instockとshippedはSORACOMサイトからSIMを購入した時の配送状況の表示ですね。
suspendedはどのような時になりますか？

Comment: それぞれのステータスの日本語との対応はご認識のとおりです。
suspendedは何らかの理由により、ソラコムがSIMの通信を強制停止する場合のために予約しているステータスで、通常の利用においては遷移することのないステータスです。